# Hibernate column doesn't exist error

Tags: java, hibernate

I am getting "column invoicelin_.invoicedraft does not exist" error. When I try to save an InvoiceDraft Object without InvoiceLine, It works well. I think There is a problem with my annotations.

my InvoiceDraft Entity;

```
//some other columns
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "uuid")
private String uuid;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy = "invoiceDraft", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<InvoiceLine> invoiceLineList;
```

InvoiceLine Entity;

```
//some other columns
@JoinColumn(name = "invoice_draft", referencedColumnName = "uuid")    
private InvoiceDraft invoiceDraft;
```

Comment: This problem is about Hibernate only. JSF nor Spring are related.

Comment: Just checking do you have a @ManyToOne annotation at the invoiceDraft?

Comment: @Carsten no i haven't. Does it necessary?

Comment: Yes I think so. I don't have a reference at hand stating it directly, but up to now I haven't seen anything suggesting otherwise. Also @JoinColumn is just specifying the relationship.

Comment: your column name invoice_draft or invoicedraft in the DB? you may need `@ManytoOne` and `@OneToMany` annotations mutually if you need two directional mapping. please post your full entity classes and DB field names.